# How can I convert a list of Either to a list of Right values?

Tags: scala, either

I do some data conversion on a list of string and I get a list of Either where Left represents an error and Right represents a successfully converted item.

```
val results: Seq[Either[String, T]] = ...
```

I partition my results with:

```
val (errors, items) = results.partition(_.isLeft)
```

After doing some error processing I want to return a `Seq[T]` of valid items. That means, returning the value of all Right elements. Because of the partitioning I already knew that all elements of items `Right`. I have come up with five possibilities of how to do it. But what is the best in readability and performance? Is there an idiomatic way of how to do it in Scala?

```
// which variant is most scala like and still understandable?
items.map(_.right.get)
items.map(_.right.getOrElse(null))
items.map(_.asInstanceOf[Right[String, T]].value)
items.flatMap(_.toOption)
items.collect{case Right(item) => item}
```

Comment: `items.collect ...` seems like a good option here.

Comment: Can you avoid the intermediate `Right`? It seems cumbersome to `collect` and it seems dangerous/unnecessary to `get`.

Comment: You might be interested in using Cats Validated for accumulating errors or results (https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) - you can avoid the boilerplate that `Either` requires, like partitioning and unnecessary `.get` calls.

Comment: `items.flatMap(_.toOption)` works well in my tests and is a clean and understandable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `.get` is considered "code smell": it will work in this case, but makes the reader of the code pause and spend a few extra "cycles" in order to "prove" that it is ok. It is better to avoid using things like `.get` on `Either` and `Option` or `.apply` on a `Map` or a `IndexedSeq`.

`.getOrElse` is ok ... but `null` is not something you often see in scala code. Again, makes the reader stop and think "why is this here? what will happen if it ends up returning null?" etc. Better to avoid as well.

`.asInstanceOf` is ... just bad. It breaks type safety, and is just ... not scala.

That leaves `.flatMap(_.toOption)` or `.collect`. Both are fine. I would personally prefer the latter as it is a bit more explicit (and does not make the reader stop to remember which way `Either` is biased).

You could also use `foldRight` to do both partition and extract in one "go":

```
 val (errors, items) = results.foldRight[(List[String], List[T])](Nil,Nil) { 
    case (Left(error), (e, i)) => (error :: e, i)
    case ((Right(result), (e, i)) => (e, result :: i)
 }
```

Comment: Should be         `case (Right(result), (e, i)) => (e, result :: i)`

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, you'll probably prefer [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partitionMap[A1,A2](f:A=%3EEither[A1,A2]):(CC[A1],CC[A2])) to [`partition`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partition(p:A=%3EBoolean):(List[A],List[A])).

It partitions elements based on a function which returns either `Right` or `Left`. Which in your case, is simply the `identity`:

```
val (lefts, rights) = List(Right(1), Left("2"), Left("3")).partitionMap(identity)
// val lefts:  List[String] = List(2, 3)
// val rights: List[Int]    = List(1)
```

which let you use lefts and rights independently and with the right types.

Answer (score 0):

Going through them one by one:

```
items.map(_.right.get)
```

You already know that these are all Rights. This will be absolutely fine.

```
items.map(_.right.getOrElse(null))
```

The `.getOrElse` is unnecessary here as you already know it should never happen. I would recommend throwing an exception if you find a Left (somehow) though, something like this: `items.map(x => x.right.getOrElse(throw new Exception(s"Unexpected Left: [$x]"))` (or whatever exception you think is suitable), rather than meddling with `null` values.

```
items.map(_.asInstanceOf[Right[String, T]].value)
```

This is unnecessarily complicated. I also can't get this to compile, but I may be doing something wrong. Either way there's no need to use `asInstanceOf` here.

```
items.flatMap(_.toOption)
```

I also can't get this to compile. `items.flatMap(_.right.toOption)` compiles for me, but at that point it'll always be a Some and you'll still have to `.get` it.

```
items.collect{case Right(item) => item}
```

This is another case of "it works but why be so complicated?". It also isn't exhaustive in the case of a Left item being there, but this should never happen so there's no need to use `.collect`.

Another way you could get the right values out is with pattern matching:

```
items.map {
  case Right(value) => value
  case other => throw new Exception(s"Unexpected Left: $other")
}
```

But again, this is probably unnecessary as you *already know* that all values will be Right.

If you are going to partition `results` like this, I recommend the first option, `items.map(_.right.get)`. Any other options either have unreachable code (code you'd never be able to hit through Unit tests or real-life operation) or are unnecessarily complicated for the sake of "looking functional".